# ADFS error while doing silent authentication

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, wif, adfs2.0

I have one SharePoint application  (App1) which has Passport authentication via ADFS authentication. I have another asp.net application in another sub domain (App2) which also has ADFS authentication. From the first application I have a $.ajax (jquery) call to control hosted in the other application.

The problem is that the FedAuth cookie was not getting posted from App1 to App2. In HTTP traces I found that the FedAuth cookie domain name was machine specific. In the web.config “federatedAuthentication” section -> cookieHandler I mentioned the domain as “microsoft.com”. This solved the issue of FedAuth not having machine name in domain property.

After this change I have hit the error below:
ID4230: The SecurityToken was not well formed. Expecting element name 'SecurityContextToken', found 'SP'.

Couldn’t find help on the net. Tried changing the path and the name attribute of cookieHandler but didn’t fix the issue. Changing the name is creating two FedAuth cookies. One with FedAuth name and one with the new name.

Special note: If open App1 after authentication and paste the URL of App2 in browser, then silent authentication works fine and I’m able to see the control of App2. The problem only comes when I call App2 control through Ajax. I’ve tried to call $.ajax “with credentials = true -> XMLHTTPRequest object) but to no avail.

Any help pointers to make the silent auth work fine through Ajax call?

Answer (score 2):

Following was my scenario.
I have a Security Token Service Provider (STS Provider) WIF Web Application and 
3 Web Clients or Relying Parties STSClient1, STSClient2 and a Sharepoint web client

I faced the same error as you mentioned if all the clients and stsprovider in the same domain, but not when all are in different domain.

In this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872350.aspx

it was mentioned that

*As for the name and path of the cookie, the name defaults to FedAuth, the path to the application directory. It can be useful to specify a unique name for the cookie, in particular if many RP applications in the solution share the same domain. Conversely, you can choose to specify a generic path when you want cookies to be shared across several apps on the same domain.*

So i went to each of the clients and provided a unique name for the cookie as below

```
<federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="[STSProviderURL]" realm="[ClientUrl]" requireHttps="false" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="[UniqueName]" />
</federatedAuthentication>
```

Comment: I knew I needed to change the cookie name to fix a problem I was having, but this was the only thing I could find that showed where the configuration setting to do it was. Thanks.